# Selenium IEDriver popup window shows session expired

Tags: popupwindow

I am encountering an issue while using the IE Web Driver. 
Whenever a pop up window opens from an IE window (IE 11) launched by the driver, the popup window will show the session has expired.

The scenario is that the driver will click on the search link text and a pop out window will be launched. The driver will then select an option from the dropdown list(country name). However, the popup window will show an expired session and therefore, could not locate the drop down list.

Has anyone experienced this type of issue before?

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("search")).click();
new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("countryCode"))).selectByVisibleText("SINGAPORE");
```